# Compose env vars in from configmap

Tags: environment-variables, openshift

I'd like to set logging level in my Wildfly Swarm app build on top of `registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift` image. The way to configure the app is through env var `JAVA_OPTIONS`, therefore I'd like to use

```
env:
- name: LOG_LEVEL
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
      name: my.configmap
      key: log.level
- name: JAVA_OPTIONS
  value: -Dswarm.logging=$LOG_LEVEL
```

Regrettably (but not really to my surprise) this doesn't work, the `LOG_LEVEL` is not resolved.

Is there a way to compose env vars from config map or do I have to modify the image to consume the env vars directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference previously defined environment variables using the following syntax:

```
env:
- name: LOG_LEVEL
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
      name: my.configmap
      key: log.level
- name: JAVA_OPTIONS
  value: -Dswarm.logging=$(LOG_LEVEL)
```

Not sure that this will work for java options on startup however, I have usually edited the image and called an entrypoint.sh file where some logic would exist but its worth a try I guess.