# how to read environment variables in context.xml in open shift

Tags: docker, tomcat, openshift

I have tried following things.

```
Added the secrets in Openshift.

Create environmental variables based on the secrets.

i have tried to refer the enviornments in tomcat context.xml using {$env.MY_KEY} , but i am unable to read it.
```

Could someone help me how to read that environment variable defined?

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that the MY_KEY environment variable is set within the pod? You can verify by opening a terminal (either via the web console or via oc rsh) and check the environment (eg via running 'env'). If the value for MY_KEY is there, it is a matter of Tomcat and how to inject environment variable values. If MY_KEY is not set, there might be something wrong with your OpenShift setup. Try to separate these two things and provide more context once you know more.

Comment: i have verified the pod using printenv command, i able to see to  environmental variables i have set in the openshift. As you said i tried to separate the things like setting up env variables and reading the env variables in context.xml. in the process of reading context.xml i have found that context.xml cannot understand custom environmental variables, we have to set CATALINA_OPTS env variable to make it understand. i follow this approach in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345962/compose-env-vars-in-from-configmap

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following syntax.

```
${env.MY_KEY}
```